# Repeating identical updates requests

Tags: windows-7, updates

Why do I keep getting updates requests that are identical? I install them and restart only to find "another update is ready to install".

Comment: Do you meant that you're seeing the same update "offered" repeatedly or do you mean that there are additional `new` updates?

Answer (score 0):

If the duplicates are coming from Microsoft, I talked to them the end of last week. I was quite upset when my antivirus kicked one out as a keystroke. They finally told me they were working on issues they planned to have resolved this week. They denied the virus, but did say they were having a issues with multiple releases of updates.